# Windows Live ID service still running after removing Windows Live

Tags: windows-7, windows, services

After deinstalling Windows Live with IObit uninstaller it first seemed to have disappeard. After some time [Windows Firewall Notifier](https://wfn.codeplex.com/) (a plugin for the Windows Firewall to show outgoing connections) popped up after booting:

*C:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\windows live\wlidsvc.exe*

aka "Microsoft Windows Live ID Service" tries to connect to

*131.253.61.82 (login.live.com.nsatc.net)*

But I have no Live ID. Never entered any credentials. I was not using Outlook or the Messenger, just the Movie Maker program for a while. Maybe it just tells Microsoft that :-)

On the other hand Live had been deinstalled. I checked the installed programs with several uninstallers: no Live installed anymore. One should think that no silent logins to Microsoft servers happen anymore. However, the "Windows Live ID Assistant" is still running as a service and does whatever it is that it has to do.

For the moment I blocked it. I am tempted to disable the service and delete the whole folder, but maybe I am overseeing something here. Is it required by Windows components?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one answer from http://community.wd.com/t5/WD-TV-Live-Networking/Windows-7-folder-sharing-how-uninstall-Windows-Live-ID-Sign-in/td-p/53100:
"You could try reinstalling it, then it may appear in the add/remove programs and you'll be able to uninstall it"
...
"That was indeed the solution - I reinstalled Windows Live and then was able to find Sign-in Assistant to uninstall."

Comment: Not working - installed [Essentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem) (Live seems to be discontinued in the meantime).  Essentials says Movie Maker is installed (it isn't). Installed Mail only. Windows completely absorbed it. Neither Live, Essentials nor Mail appears in Add/Remove programs. It is nice to offer these "Essentials" but not-so-nice to make them sticky, and to leave people alone with discontinued software that still phones home. [TINSTAAFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain%27t_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch) I guess. In other words, we're here to learn :-)